# Using regex with LIKE to sort alphabets first then symbols SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, select, sql-order-by

I have the following MySQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM `travels`.`destinations` AS `Des`
WHERE `Des`.`name` LIKE '%act%' AND `Des`.`sold` = 'N' AND `Des`.`active` = '1'
GROUP BY `Des`.`name` ORDER BY CASE
WHEN `Des`.`name` REGEX 'act*' THEN 0
WHEN `Des`.`name` LIKE '%act' THEN 1
WHEN `Des`.`name` LIKE '%act%' THEN 2
ELSE 3 END, name LIMIT 10
```

What I am trying to achieve:

`actabc
actzzz
abcact
zzzact
abcactzzz
act-act`

When I use this group by mechanism, it is showing hyphenated result first, which it should. I want alphabets first, then symbols and then numbers. In the same order of wild cards.

These are working individually:
[How to sort MySQL results with letters first, symbols last?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641370/how-to-sort-mysql-results-with-letters-first-symbols-last)
and
This is sort of confusing (and doesn't give the group by as I want either):
[mysql regex get position of matched first alphabetic character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848117/mysql-regex-get-position-of-matched-first-alphabetic-character)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM travels.destinations AS D
WHERE D.name LIKE '%act%' AND D.sold = 'N' AND D.active = '1'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN D.name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]*$' AND D.name LIKE 'act%' THEN 0
              WHEN D.name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]*$' AND D.name LIKE '%act' THEN 1
              WHEN D.name REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z]*$' AND D.name LIKE '%act%' THEN 2
              ELSE 3 
         END, 
         D.name 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks...
But it shows Syntax error:  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX '^[a-zA-Z]*$' AND

Comment: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Comment: Also tried changing '^[a-zA-Z]*$' to '^[a-zA-Z]+' No go