# MySQL Sort Query with Special Character

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have to sort one column of `mytable` in `ascending order` but problem is `mytable` contains some special characters related data. Still I want to sort in ascending order so that it display in proper manner in UI.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried using

```
ORDER BY Item DESC
```

But it gives me first `ABC` type rows then `{ABC}` type rows.Means giving special characters in last

Comment: may be check 1by1 char of each row is alphanumeric then remove it and then use sort

Comment: A similar question exists [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665049/using-regex-with-like-to-sort-alphabets-first-then-symbols-sql](here), which shows how to use RegEx to sort and filter. It might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for your problem :

```
select * from mytable ORDER BY REGEXP_REPLACE(Item,'[^[:alnum:]'' '']', NULL) DESC
```